# Is it possible to define a C++ member function who's definition is local to a file and therefore allow multiple versions to coexist

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

I'm trying to make a string class that can convert automatically to and from std::string.

```
class MyString
{
  MyString(const std::string)
  {
    ...
  }
};
```

The issue is different compilers can have different layouts of std::string (e.g. Visual Studio 2010 vs 2015). So this constructor or autocast operator must be a function local to each compilation unit, AKA a static function. But you can't simply declare the member as static because the meaning isn't the same.

I know a guaranteed solution is to use a non-member function to do conversions and declare that as static. But would really appreciate a member function.

```
static MyString StringToMyString(const std::string& s);
```

Comment: That sounds like you are deliberately trying to break the "one definition rule"?

Comment: *The issue is different compilers can have different layouts of std::string* That shouldn't matter.  The interface for `std::string` doesn't change, as it's guaranteed by the standard, so you just need to program against the interface, not the implemenation

Comment: You want to compile different files with different compilers...?

Comment: No, I don't think I'm breaking the 1 definition rule. It makes exceptions for inline and static functions. I was thinking of marking that function as FORCE_INLINE. But it's not guaranteed the compiler will always inline a member function.

Comment: ***different compilers can have different layouts of std::string*** Why is that an issue? Is your code directly accessing the internal layout of a `std::string` instead of using its interface?

Comment: "I'm trying to make a string class that can convert automatically to and from std::string". That would be an extremely bad idea. "The issue is different compilers can have different layouts of std::string (e.g. Visual Studio 2010 vs 2015)." Combining different compilers in a single program would be an extremely bad idea on its own. It can be done but it's not for the faint of heart. "would really appreciate a member function" That's provided you somehow survive the two previous catastrophes. You can't have local member functions anyway, so much for that idea.

Comment: @drescherjm Are you familiar with the dual ABI libstdc++ saga? Why do you think it happened?

Comment: I am not that familiar with the libstdc++ saga. I do however know that on windows it's not safe to mix and match versions of Visual Studio in the same application. The only binary compatibility is between VS 2015 and 2019 all other versions of Visual Studio are binary incompatible at least when it comes to c++.

Comment: What do you need to do that can't be accomplished by using `.c_str()` to get the raw data of the string?

Comment: @drescherjm well you should look it up, and then stop assuming that accessing only the published interface of a library shields you from internal changes therein.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Are you talking about this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: ***then stop assuming that accessing only the published interface of a library shields you from internal changes therein.*** I certainly did not assume that at all. I was just attempting to understand why the OP wanted this. My assumption was the application would be linked to libraries from a single version of Visual Studio and no mixing of runtimes or compiler versions would occur. I was trying to understand the use case. Although this may have been an incorrect assumption.

Comment: I'm not mixing different compilers in the same project ! But another another team will be calling our API using a different compiler or STL implementation. There might be another solution to this. If I just have a constructor that takes const char* then C++ will auto cast std::string to const char*

Comment: @Cory Kramer. Actually, this does conceptually go against the 1 definition rule, so a solution seems unlikely

Comment: ***But another another team will be calling our API using a different compiler or STL implementation.*** Won't they compile your library with the same compiler that they will use for their code or are you only giving out binaries with no source for a particular compiler and you think there is a way to make it work on any c++ implementation?

Comment: It seems that your goal is building a packaged C++ library usable by a different compiler. If so, then you absolutely should not write any such string class, or try bending the rules of the language. It is necessary and sufficient to make external interfaces of your library compatible with C. C ABIs are stable, C++ ABIs are not. So yes, `const char*` instead of `std::string` or any other class. C doesn't have classes.

Comment: Based on your guy's warnings and seeing what QT does, I conclude it's not feasible to do this. QString in QT 3.3  did have a constructors that took std::string. But now in QT 5, it was ***changed to a non-member*** function, static inline QString fromStdString

Answer (score 0):

I've considered forced inlining (even when optimizations are off), symbol aliasing, and symbol versioning and found forced inlining to be the simplest and most portable. __attribute__((alias)), requires the mangled C++ name and symbol versioning only works for shared libs and requires dynamic linker support. Here's an example that has 2 layouts for class My.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NO_INLINE __attribute__((noinline))
#define FORCE_INLINE __attribute__((always_inline))

class My
{
public:
  FORCE_INLINE My(const String& s)
  {
    printf("creating from %s size=%d\n",s.s,(int)sizeof(s));
    Construct(s.s);
  }
  NO_INLINE void Construct(const char* s)
  {
    printf("Construct(%s)\n",s);
  }
};
void LibFunction();
#ifdef CLIENT
int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
  String s;
  s.s="string1";
  My my(s);
  LibFunction();
  return 0;
}
#else
void LibFunction()
{
  String s;
  s.s="string2";
  My my(s);
}
#endif
```

The output is this and is the same with or without optimizations

```
creating from string1 size=48
Construct(string1)
creating from string2 size=8
Construct(string2)
```

I've also investigated how QT deals with multiple layouts. In version 3.3, https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qstring-h.html, it doesn't seem to:

```
class Q_EXPORT QString
{
    QString( const std::string& );
};
```

Now, it's no longer a member function, but a private function to each compilation unit, presumably to allow multiple string layouts

```
class Q_CORE_EXPORT QString
{
  static inline QString fromStdString(const std::string &s);
};
```